# Losing query string by refreshing page in Nextjs using express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a problem with nextjs and none of solutions helped me!!! I, m trying to have a dynamic route in my SSR project, everything is working well in localhost, but when I try to upload it to the server or my IIS problem shows on 
:  The problem is this that everything works fine at first render from the server and after refreshing the page I lose my query string and Undefined error happens.  Here are my codes:

Server.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3003;

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get("/", (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, "/index");
  });

  server.get("/test?org&des&roomRules&departing&returning", (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, "/test" , {
      org: req.query.org ,
      des: req.query.des,
      roomRules:req.query.roomRules,
      departing: req.query.departing,
      returning: req.query.returning,
    });
  });

  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });
  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`READY ON  http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Parent Component:

```
const RoundButton = props => {
  const { searchParams , name} = props;
  const URL2 = `/test?org=${searchParams.org}&des=${searchParams.des}&roomRules=${searchParams.roomRules}&departing=${searchParams.orgDate}&returning=${searchParams.desDate}`;
  return (
    <Link  href={URL2} as={URL2}>
      Test
    </Link>
  );
};
```

Test Componet :

```
function Test(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <h2>roomrules :{props.queryStrings}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

Test.getInitialProps =  ({query}) => {
  const queryStrings =  query;
  return {
     queryStrings: queryStrings 
  };    
};

export default Test
```

As you can see I used getInitialProps and it only works on first render.

And finally my scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node server.js",
  "build": "next build && next export",
  "start": " node server.js"
},
```

To publish I write "npm run build" in cmd. Any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the next js you can use the following approach to make the URL parameter persistent in refresh:
Assume you had a component named TestComponent:

```
TestComponent.getInitialProps = async (context: any) => {
  const { oid } = context.query;
  return { id: oid };
};
```

The oid is the parameter that you want to be persistent after page refresh and not be undefined.

```
export default function TestComponent(props: any) {
     props.id
}
```

This is the approach that you are using in the source code, the other approach is as follow:

```
export default function TestComponent(props: any){
  const router = useRouter();
  const { oid } = router.query;
}
```

now you have access to the oid and for the useEffect function use the following approach:

```
export default function TestComponent(props: any){
      const router = useRouter();
      const { oid } = router.query;
      useEffect(function(){
       }, [oid])
    }
```

with this setup, your code should also work on Refresh, consider if you have multiple calls to fetch data from the server you have to check that multiple requests precisely.